# ImportError when trying to import a module from within a package

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to wrap my head around this, but I can't find an answer on google, though it should be fairly simple...

My project layout is currently something like this :

```
project/
    main.py
    config/
        ...
    lib/
        __init__.py
        constants.py
        functions.py
        some_class.py
```

Now, I need some constants defined in `constants.py` in `some_class.py`, and some functions from `functions.py` too. So, naturally, I did :

```
from constants import *
from functions import *
```

in my `some_class.py` file.

my `main.py` file looks something like that :

```
from lib.some_class import Class
from lib.constants import *
from lib.functions import *
```

which works fine.

But I get an `ImportError` whenever I try to import constants and functions in my `some_class.py` file. I tried not importing, as I thought that might not be necessary, given that I'm within the package itself, but constants defined in `constants.py` were not defined in `some_class.py`. I'm a bit lost here...

Comment: Use the excactly same line as in `main.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm dumb. Leaving an answer here if anyone stumble on the same kind of issue.

I should have used `from .constants import *`, so that python knows that it is in the lib package (instead of `from constants import *`, the dot matters)